# Hangman Python 3 about matching

Tags: python-3.x, matching

I'm having problem coding a simple hangman game. For the example, the mystery 
word is "btta" and the user is to guess the word by inputting a letter each 
turn.For example a letter "t" is entered, it will fill "t" in the index 1 of the 
    declared list box in relation to the index of "batt". After filling index1 of 
    box  (['*','t','*','_']) it wont fill t in the index 2. How can I solve it?

```
riddle='btta'         //Mystery word that user needs to guess
length=len(riddle)
listriddle=list(riddle)
**box**=['_','_','_','_']  // a list where guessed letters are stored to form the mystery word
wrongcount=0

while(wrongcount<7):
     guess=str(input("Enter a letter: "))
     g=0
     while(g<length):
        if((listriddle[g]==guess) & (box[g]=='_')):
              zebra=listriddle.index(guess)
              box[zebra]=guess
              print(box)
              g+=1
        else:
             g+=1
    print('Try Again')
    wrongcount+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ((listriddle[g] == guess) & (box[g] == '_')):
        box[g] = guess
        print(box)
        g += 1
    else:
        g += 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's usually better to provide an explanation of why and how this code helps in this case. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)